# How to re-export Tauri command function from Rust module?

Tags: rust, tauri

**Questions**

I'm new to Rust and Tauri. I'm not sure why I can't properly re-export function (`pub use`) and use it in tauri::generate_handler.

**Code**

`src/main.rs`

```
mod util;

fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![util::add])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

`src/util/mod.rs`

```
mod operation;

// pub use operation::add; // This line not work as expected
pub use operation::*; // This line no problem
```

`src/util/operation.rs`

```
#[tauri::command]
pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}
```

I'm not sure why `pub use operation::add;` not work as expect and cause

```
failed to resolve: could not find `__cmd__add` in `util`
could not find `__cmd__add` in `util` rustc
```

in `tauri::generate_handler!`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I suspect that `tauri::command` creates a new symbol named `__cmd__add` and that `tauri::generate_handler` uses that symbol instead of (or in addition to) `add` itself. When you `use operation::*` you import everything from `operation`, including `__cmd__add`. But when you `use operation::add` you only import `add`. Can you try with `pub use operation::{ add, __cmd__add };`?

Comment: @Jmb This is a bad idea. `__cmd__add` ought to be a private implementation detail.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that wasn't meant as a solution but as a way to test my hypothesis. A clean solution may require some changes to Tauri, or wrapping the `add` command in a module and exporting that module so that the generated symbol(s) will be accessible.

Comment: @Jmb That solve the problem.
@ChayimFriedman What do you think about `pub use operation::*;`. It actually also export `__cmd__add`. Or it just not a good approach to put `tauri::command` function into module.

Comment: @PeterWong This is of course subjective, but I think glob imports are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `tauri::command` creates a new symbol named `__cmd__add` and that `tauri::generate_handler` uses that symbol instead of (or in addition to) `add` itself. When you `use operation::*` you import everything from `operation`, including `__cmd__add`. But when you `use operation::add` you only import `add`.

A dirty workaround would be to `use operation::{ add, __cmd__add }`, but this is discouraged because `__cmd__add` is a private implementation detail, not intended to be used directly.

A full fix would require changes to Tauri, but a possible workaround for you is to wrap `add` in a module so that `tauri::generate_handler` will find `__cmd__add` inside that module:

- In `src/util/operation.rs`:

  ```
  pub mod add {
      #[tauri::command]
      pub fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
          a + b
      }
  }
  pub use add::add;
  ```
- In `src/util/mod.rs`:

  ```
  mod operation;
  pub use operation::add;
  ```
- In `src/main.rs`:

  ```
  mod util;

  fn main() {
      tauri::Builder::default()
          // Note the double `add` here:
          .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![util::add::add])
          .run(tauri::generate_context!())
          .expect("error while running tauri application");
  }
  ```

Note that when calling `tauri::generate_handler` you need to refer explicitly to the `add` function that's inside the `add` module, so you need to use `add::add`. However when you want to call the function from your Rust code you can do it directly: `let four = util::add (2, 2)` will work fine.